# Can i make SimPy Sum(Indexed(Random_probabilistic_Variable, i ), (i,1,n)) works?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, probability

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import *
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x, y, a, b, i, n, t, z, mi, sigma, theta, μ, σ, σ2, θ, λ = symbols('x y a b i n t z mi sigma theta μ σ σ2 θ λ')

pdf = θ*x**(θ-1)
X = ContinuousRV(x, pdf, set=Interval(0, 1))
Y = Sum(Indexed(X,i),(i,1,n))
E(1/ln(Y))
```

I Cant find on documentation how i can do what im trying here,I probably have to solve it manually using linear algebra and I calculate

It dont works cause 'X' is not a symbol (of Symbols()).
is there any way to do this? to return a sum of random ​​(probabilistic) variables.

X is a random variable (of the probability matter of my graduation (statistics))

pdf is its probability density function

I would like to know the spectance of 'Y' (function(math) of the random variable(prob) x) Y = 1/sum(X)

error:

```
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9912/3953641788.py in <module>
      7 pdf = θ*x**(θ-1)
      8 X = ContinuousRV(x, pdf, set=Interval(0, 1))
----> 9 Y = Sum(Indexed(X,i),(i,1,n))
     10 E(1/ln(Y))

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor\indexed.py in __new__(cls, base, *args, **kw_args)
    154             base = IndexedBase(base)
    155         elif not hasattr(base, '__getitem__') and not isinstance(base, IndexedBase):
--> 156             raise TypeError(filldedent("""
    157                 The base can only be replaced with a string, Symbol,
    158                 IndexedBase or an object with a method for getting


TypeError: 
The base can only be replaced with a string, Symbol, IndexedBase or an
object with a method for getting items (i.e. an object with a
`__getitem__` method).*
```

Comment: Could you show the variables?  I can't run that code in my head.  Look at other sympy questions to see what a well formatted question and answer looks like.

Comment: Show all imports, and show the exact error message.  Remember that only a fraction of the `sympy` views have worked with `ContinuousRV` (where is that from), and thus don't know what what `X` is.  Do you even know?  How can this object be used?  What do the docs say?

Comment: I don't know of a way to represent a sum of IID random variables with sympy's stats module. I expect that if there was then you still wouldn't be able to get any simple answer since the integrals will be impossible. Try just doing this for two variables like `E(1/log(X1 + X2))`.

Comment: The error occurs in the `Indexed(X,i)` expression.  As described in the error, it has specific requirements for the `base` object.